# mysql syntax shows error when updating user profile

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I am trying to use a sql query to change some fields in wp_usermeta and when I put this snippet:

```
 UPDATE wp_usermeta
 SET meta_value = IF("meta_key" = 'first_name', '{firstname}', IF("meta_key" = 'last_name', '{lastname}', "meta_value"))
 WHERE user_id =
 (SELECT "user_id" FROM
 (SELECT MAX("user_id") AS "user_id"
 FROM wp_usermeta) AS `reg`)
 AND ("meta_key" = 'first_name'
 OR "meta_key" = 'last_name')
```

SQL works fine. But when I want to add a new meta_key in this snippet it displays the error:

```
 UPDATE wp_usermeta
  SET meta_value = IF("meta_key" = 'first_name', '{firstname}', IF("meta_key" = 'last_name', '{lastname}', IF("meta_key" = 'telephone', '{phone}', "meta_value"))
  WHERE user_id =
   (SELECT "user_id" FROM
   (SELECT MAX("user_id") AS "user_id"
  FROM wp_usermeta) AS `reg`)
  AND ("meta_key" = 'first_name'
   OR "meta_key" = 'last_name'
   OR "meta_key" = 'telephone')
```

There is an error - **in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE**

Please help me to solve this issue. I am just to begun to work with MySQL and don't know much.

Comment: You are using single quotes around column names.  I consider this a typographical error and vote to close such questions.

Comment: changed to double quotes but didn't help...

Comment: Sorry @GordonLinoff Linoff can you please explain how can I fix my typographical error on this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the beginning of your query:

```
UPDATE wp_usermeta
    SET meta_value = IF("meta_key" = 'first_name', '{firstname}',
                        IF("meta_key" = 'last_name', '{lastname}',
                            IF("meta_key" = 'telephone', '{phone}', "meta_value"
                              )
                          )
-----------------------^
```

(There is a reason why good programmers are maniacal about formatting; it prevents lots of errors like this.)

The problem is that you are missing a closing paren.  You should write this using `case` (standard SQL):

```
UPDATE wp_usermeta
    SET meta_value = (CASE WHEN meta_key = 'first_name' THEN '{firstname}'
                           WHEN meta_key = 'last_name' THEN '{lastname}'
                           WHEN meta_key = 'telephone' THEN '{phone}'
                           ELSE meta_value
                       END)
    WHERE user_id = (SELECT user_id
                     FROM (SELECT MAX(user_id) AS user_id
                           FROM wp_usermeta
                          ) reg
                    ) AND
          meta_key IN ('first_name', 'last_name', 'telephone');
```

Don't use quotes for column names unless you really have to.  And if you have to, then change the names so you don't have to.

EDIT:

You can also write this as:

```
UPDATE wp_usermeta
    SET meta_value = (CASE WHEN meta_key = 'first_name' THEN '{firstname}'
                           WHEN meta_key = 'last_name' THEN '{lastname}'
                           WHEN meta_key = 'telephone' THEN '{phone}'
                           ELSE meta_value
                       END)
    WHERE meta_key IN ('first_name', 'last_name', 'telephone')
    ORDER BY user_id DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```